# Devices which consume substantial power in modern embedded real-time systems?

Tags: embedded, low-power, device

Could anybody cite examples (if any) of devices and peripherals in modern embedded and real-time systems which consume substantial amount of power compared to modern processors. As processors get more and more power efficient, some devices simply don't scale in their power efficincy as much as modern processors do.

Any links for analysis of power distribution in embedded systems would be much appreciated.

Comment: To add to the "too broad" votes: I have an 8-bit MCU connected to a 250hp V8 petrol engine.

Answer (score 2):

[Content-addressable memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_storage) can be quite a big sink of power. A CAM differs from a ram because you don't provide an address and receive some data, but you provide some data and (maybe) receive an address. Basically you fill up your CAM with data in known positions, then you put your data as the CAM input and if there's a match the chip tells you the address where the content is stored. This leads to high power consumption since at each clock cycle *all* the memory words must be compared with the input, that's a lot of circuitry at work.

CAMs can be useful in various applications, a couple of examples:
**processor cache**: you keep in a piece of CAM the addresses of the RAM pages that are loaded in cache at the address where they are loaded, when the CPU needs to execute an I/O operation first of all checks if the I/O address is in the CAM, if it is the CAM answers with the cache address and the CPU may look there.
**image processing**: you keep in a piece of cam some bit patterns that correspond to a small tile, then you scan an image tile by tile, if you get a CAM hit you substitute the tile with the CAM address, compressing the image.

this last application is quite innovative (currently used pretty much only at CERN accelerator), researchers are working to apply it to consumer products such as cameras, smartphones or whatever, and one of the biggest issues is power consumption.

Comment: TCAMs are popular in network processing.  A TCAM is a cam that basically doesnt look for exact matches but masks and then matches so you can have multiple patterns give the same result.  A TCAM for example can be used to find all 10.x.x.x packets or route port 80 packets to one server and port 22 to another.  you could have rules for the entire ip header and mask off various parts depending on what you want to search on but have a generic all ip header search for each packet...

Answer (score 2):

Actuators: linear- and rotary solenoids, motors including steppers, servos. It still takes roughly the same amount of energy input to do a given amount of work. Robotic laboratory analyzers are one example. As computing ability increases, even with less applied electric power, the machines get 'smarter' and more complex in their record keeping and anlytical capabilities, but the prime movers are still the big power consumers.

Comment: +1.  This answer also highlights that this question is very broad.  What do we consider an embedded system for the purposes of this question?  Do we consider a 2kW motor driver a part of the embedded system?  Do we consider a 10A battery charger a part of the embedded system?  The question is also unclear, because it lacks the context.  What will the findings be applied to?

Comment: Fair enough - prime movers and other controlled devices might better be regarded as part the host - the controlled device - rather than as part of the embedded system.